Seleccionar un QCheckBox externo para marcar o desmarcar varios QCheckBox de un QTableWiget
En PyQt6 cree una tabla (tab_pacientes), la cual se carga correctamente. Además, tengo un checkbox  externo a la tabla (chk_todos), el cual utilizo para marcar o desmarcar todos los checkboxes contenidos en la primera columna de la misma. Ambos están contenidos en un Qdialog.
En el método marcar_todos está la lógica para el marcado/desmarcado, pero no realiza nada. He intentado solucionarlo de varias formas, pero no encuentro la solución. Les agradecería por su apoyo.
Aquí comparto el código:
from datetime import date
from PyQt6 import uic
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor, QBrush
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QCheckBox, QDialog, QVBoxLayout

from Data.Psicologia_Data import PsicologoData

class MovCarteraPsi():
    def __init__(self):
        self.movcar = uic.loadUi('Gui/PsicologiaReev.ui')
        self.movcar.show()
        self.movcar.move(20,70)
        self.iniciaGUI()
        
    def iniciaGUI(self ):
        self.movcar.chk_todos.stateChanged.connect(self.marcar_todos)
        self.mostrar_psicologo()
        self.cargar_tabla()
        self.movcar.cbx_psipad.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.cargar_tabla)
        
    def mostrar_psicologo(self):
        psi_data = PsicologoData()
        psicologos = psi_data.obtener_psicologos()

        for psicologo in psicologos:
            self.movcar.cbx_psipad.addItem(psicologo[1])
        
    def cargar_tabla(self):
        pacData = PsicologoData()
        psi_buscado = self.movcar.cbx_psipad.currentText()
        pacientes = pacData.obtener_pacreevaludos_por_psicologo(psi_buscado)
        cabeceras = ['Chk', 'Id', 'Cod_Pac', 'Pac', 'Fec_Inicio', 'Fec_Fin', 'ns', 'Direccion', 'Distrito', 'Usuario' ]
        self.movcar.tab_pacientes.clear()
        self.movcar.tab_pacientes.setColumnCount(len(cabeceras))
        self.movcar.tab_pacientes.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(cabeceras)
        
        # Ajustar los anchos de las columnas
        ancho_columnas = [1, 65, 65, 250, 80, 80, 3, 250, 130, 100]
        
        for i, ancho in enumerate(ancho_columnas):
            self.movcar.tab_pacientes.setColumnWidth(i, ancho)
            
        # llenando la tabla con los datos y limpiando datos
        posiciones_deseadas = [0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14]
        self.movcar.tab_pacientes.setRowCount(0)
        
        for paciente in pacientes:
            ind = self.movcar.tab_pacientes.rowCount()
            self.movcar.tab_pacientes.insertRow(ind)
            chk = QCheckBox()  # Crear instancia de QCheckBox
            chk.setChecked(False)  # Opcional: desmarcar inicialmente el checkbox
            chk.setStyleSheet("margin-left:15%; margin-right:15%;")
            chk.stateChanged.connect(lambda state, row=ind: self.marcar_fila(state, row))  # Conectar la señal
            self.movcar.tab_pacientes.setCellWidget(ind, 0, chk)
            
            valores_deseados = [paciente[pos] for pos in posiciones_deseadas]
            for col, valor in enumerate(valores_deseados):
                if col == 3 or col == 4:
                    if isinstance(valor, date):
                        fecha_formateada = valor.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
                        item = QTableWidgetItem(fecha_formateada)
                    else:
                        item = QTableWidgetItem(str(valor))
                else:
                    item = QTableWidgetItem(str(valor))
                self.movcar.tab_pacientes.setItem(ind, col + 1, item)
                # centra contenido de la col ID
                if col == 0 or col == 5:
                    item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        
        self.movcar.tab_pacientes.update()
    
    def marcar_fila(self, state, row):
        # print(f"Checkbox at row {row} changed to state {state}")
        match Qt.CheckState(state):
            case Qt.CheckState.Checked:
                color = QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.yellow)
            case Qt.CheckState.Unchecked:
                color = QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.white)
        for col in range(1, self.movcar.tab_pacientes.columnCount()):
            item = self.movcar.tab_pacientes.item(row, col)
            if item:
                item.setBackground(QBrush(color))
                # print(f"Set color of row {row}, col {col} to {color.name()}")
                
    def marcar_todos(self, state):
        print(f"External checkbox changed to state {state}")
        for row in range(self.movcar.tab_pacientes.rowCount()):
            cell_widget = self.movcar.tab_pacientes.cellWidget(row, 0)
            if cell_widget:
                check_box = cell_widget.findChild(QCheckBox)
                if state == Qt.CheckState.Checked.value:
                    check_box.setChecked(True)
                elif state == Qt.CheckState.Unchecked.value:
                    check_box.setChecked(False)

En algunos casos sale este error:
check_box.setChecked(True)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setChecked'


El error nos da una gran pista de la que tirar:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setChecked' quiere decir que check_box es None.

Si check_box es None significa que cell_widget.findChild(QCheckBox) retorna None.

findChild retorna None si no encuentra ningún widget hijo con ese tipo.


Y no encuentra ninguno porque estás haciendo esto en cargar_tabla:
chk = QCheckBox()  # Crear instancia de QCheckBox
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...     
self.movcar.tab_pacientes.setCellWidget(ind, 0, chk)
                                                ^^^

Estás agregando como widget raíz de la celda al propio CheckBox, por lo que en marcar_todos al hacer:
cell_widget = self.movcar.tab_pacientes.cellWidget(row, 0)

cell_widget es ya el propio CheckBox, sobre el cual intentas luego buscar un hijo que no tiene. Tu método marcar_todos sería correcto si estuvieras asignando otro widget a la celda, como un QTableWidgetItem, que a su vez contendría al CheckBox como hijo.
Si vas a asignar el checkbox directamente a la celda el método debe ser algo así:
def marcar_todos(self, state):
    state = Qt.CheckState(state)
    for row in range(self.movcar.tab_pacientes.rowCount()):
        if check_box := self.movcar.tab_pacientes.cellWidget(row, 0):
            check_box.setCheckState(state)

Si estás seguro de no tener filas vacías en la tabla puedes prescindir del condicional:
def marcar_todos(self, state):
    state = Qt.CheckState(state)
    for row in range(self.movcar.tab_pacientes.rowCount()):
        self.movcar.tab_pacientes.cellWidget(row, 0).setCheckState(state)


FJSevilla las gracias respectivas por dar respuesta a mi inquitud, encontre la solucion al problema que tuve por la respuesta que me diste, como siempre son muy acertadas, mi gratitud por compartir tus conocimientos, esta es la solucion.

esta es la solucion, gracias FJSevilla por tu recomendacion, tenias razon, al comprobar tu codigo solo salio un error pequeño, pero realize las correcciones, recordando que anteriormente me ayudaste con otro problema parecido y encontre la solucion, seguro que tu ayuda fue valiosa para llegar a la solucion, la cual la comparto
def marcar_todos(self, state):
        match Qt.CheckState(state):
            case Qt.CheckState.Checked:
                state = Qt.CheckState.Checked
            case Qt.CheckState.Unchecked:
                state = Qt.CheckState.Unchecked
        
        for row in range(self.movcar.tab_pacientes.rowCount()):
            checkbox = self.movcar.tab_pacientes.cellWidget(row, 0)
            checkbox.setCheckState(state)


Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
